# google closureCompiler doesn't want to read my goog.getMsg()

Tags: gruntjs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I'm trying to compile my js files using closure compiler, but it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR - goog.getMsg() function could be used only with MSG_* property or variable
```

my closureCompiler options are:

```
closureCompiler: {
    options: {
        compilerFile: 'temp/compiler.jar',
        compilerOpts: {
            compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
            //compilation_level: 'WHITESPACE_ONLY',
            language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
            language_out: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
            formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT',
            externs: ['src/js/compiled/react-extern.js'],
            warning_level: 'verbose',
            summary_detail_level: 3,
            output_wrapper: '"(function(){%output%}).call(window);"',
            create_source_map: 'src/js/compiled/output.js.map',
            manage_closure_dependencies: true,
            use_types_for_optimization: null,
            debug: true
        },
        execOpts: {
            maxBuffer: 999999 * 1024
        }
    },
    compile: {
        //src: 'src/js/debug/**/*.js',
        src: [
            'temp/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js', 
            'src/js/compiled/test.js'
        ],
        dest: 'src/js/compiled/compiled.js'
    },
},
```

I believe I'm missing a flag, but I don't which one to write ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include goog.getMsg() in your code.
It has to be:

```
var MSG_SOMETHING = goog.getMsg('something');
```

and use the MSG_SOMETHING instead.
Google Closure Compiler enforced that, so you could write all your variable in one file and send this one to get translated.